# Virtual host or htaccess not redirecting non-www to www anymore

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web, virtual, host

After a server reinstall from debian 6 to debian 7 wheezy one of our pages stoped redirecting non-www to www version. The strange thing is, that on all other virtual hosts its working perfectly fine.

Here the virtual virtual host (enabled):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin info@ravand.org
     ServerName ravand.org
     ServerAlias *.ravand.org
     DocumentRoot /var/www/ravand.org/forum/
     ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ravand.org/ravand.org_error.log
     CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ravand.org/ravand.org_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And here our .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php?page=Portal
# WCF-SEO-START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ravand.org$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.ravand.org/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^tag/([0-9]+)\-([^/\.]*)/?$ index.php?page=TaggedObjects&tagID=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/([^/\.]*)/?$ index.php?page=User&userID=$1&username=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+/)*([^/\.]+)/([0-9]+)\-([^/\.]*)/last\-post\.html$ index.php?page=Thread&threadID=$3&action=lastPost [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+/)*([^/\.]+)/([0-9]+)\-([^/\.]*)/first\-new\-post\.html$ index.php?page=Thread&threadID=$3&action=firstNew [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+/)*([^/\.]+)/p([0-9]+)\-([^/\.]*)/?$ index.php?page=Thread&postID=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+/)*([^/\.]+)/([0-9]+)\-([^/\.]*)/index([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?page=Thread&threadID=$3&pageNo=$5 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+/)*([^/\.]+)/([0-9]+)\-([^/\.]*)/?$ index.php?page=Thread&threadID=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+/)*([^/\.]+)/index([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?page=Board&boardTitle=$2&pageNo=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+/)*([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=Board&boardTitle=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)\.html$ index.php?page=Index [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
# WCF-SEO-END
```

When you try to connect to the page without www it just gives you the standard "Nothing to see here" message from apache2
This configuration used to work before the reinstall, so what could be the cause of this?

Also rewrite engine is already turned on.

Thanks in Advance
ravand

Comment: Did you move your document root? And where is the htaccess located?

Comment: No everything is exactly where it was before. The .htaccess is in /var/www/ravand.org/forum/